# Buildozer, cannot compute sizeof (size_t)

Tags: android, python, compiler-errors, kivy

I'm trying to compile my kivy app with buildozer.  I'm using windows with the the kivy Android virtual machine.

```
configure: error: in '/home/kivy/Mole/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for- android/build/python/Python-2.7.2':
configure: error: cannot compute sizeof (size_t)
See 'config.log' for more details
checking size of size_t... # command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "molebash"
```

I'm not sure where to find/access the 'config.log', if anyone knows roughly where this is stored I can add that too.

Apologies for the brief description but I'm not sure what information will help in fixing this problem.  If you let me know I'll post any other information you may need.

Thanks!

Comment: No solution, but similar errors seem to have been a result of platform specific setups.  http://bugs.python.org/issue17344 might provide some insight.  Post near the bottom solves someone's issue because a specific command argument wasn't compatible with the bitness of the user's operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching I found the solution!
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/ZX_M-pu6kK0

in your buildozer spec file find these lines and alter them as follows:

```
(str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk = 8c

(str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
android.ndk_path = ~/android/android-ndk-r8c

(str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
android.sdk_path = ~/android/android-sdk-linux

(str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
android.p4a_dir = ~/android/python-for-android
```

This links buildozer with the SDK/NDK/P4A that are within the kivy virtual machine.

If you don't set these up buildozer will automatically download new copies.  Presumably the problem was caused by how buildozer downloaded/installed these new copies.  Someone with better knowledge of buildozer may be able shed light on the cause of this problem!.